# I have pandas dataframe which contains two columns (column A & column B)

Tags: python, regex

In column A  there are 3 sentences (ABC,DEF,GHI). The sentence starts with     <s><s>& **ends with "</s></s> "
**

For example: This is one single sentence

```
 Column A                           Column B

(('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
(('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
(('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
(('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076
(('abc', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.011148272017837236
```

When ever a sentence  ends with  closing tag "'), ''"  i want to multiply  column B all the rows of a particular sentence
Example: (0.04302521*0.65234375*0.04259502*0.186046512*0.413173653*0.011148272=1.02452)

I want to get an output per this data frame

```
 Column A                           Column B



 (('<s>', '<s>'),  'abc')            0.043025210084033615
 (('<s>', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.65234375
 (('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.04259501965923984
 (('abc', 'abc'),  'abc')            0.18604651162790697
 (('abc', 'abc'),  '</s>')           0.41317365269461076
 (('abc', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.011148272017837236
 (('<s>', '<s>'),  'def')            0.09090909090909091
 (('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.008287292817679558
 (('def', 'def'),  'def')            0.13506493506493505
 (('def', 'def'),  '</s>')           0.007653061224489796
 (('def', '</s>'), '</s>')           0.08333333333333333
 (('<s>', '<s>'),  'ghi')            0.5
 (('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.125
 (('ghi', 'ghi'),  'ghi')            0.033766233766233764
 (('ghi', 'ghi'),  '</s>')           0.0694980694980695
 (('ghi','</s>'),  '</s>')           0.16666666666666666
```

Output should be :(0.04302521*0.65234375*0.04259502*0.186046512*0.413173653*0.011148272=1.02452)
(0.090909091*0.008287293*0.135064935*0.007653061*0.083333333=6.48958)
(0.5*0.125*0.033766234*0.069498069*0.166666667=2.44447)

The output should be in the below format
1.02452
6.48958
2.44447

Comment: will you always have `('<s>', '<s>')` before a new "bloc" for a same sentence?

Comment: break the rows containing </s>), </s> the string pattern from a Pandas dataframe i want to multiply column B all the rows of a particular sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to create a column 'sentence' to use `groupby` later. Let's say your dataframe is called `df`. I create this column with 0.

```
df['sentence'] = 0
```

Now, put 1 in this column where the Column A contains `('<s>', '<s>')` and then use `cumsum` to have a different number for each sentence:

```
df['sentence'].loc[df['Column A'].str.contains("('<s>', '<s>')")] = 1
df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].cumsum()
```

What you need to do is to groubpy this column and use `prod`

```
df.groupby('sentence')['Column B'].prod()
Out[527]: 
sentence
1.0    1.024519e-06
2.0    6.489579e-08
3.0    2.444467e-05
Name: Column B, dtype: float64
```

Depending on how exactly you wan the result, you can use `df.groupby('sentence')['Column B'].prod().tolist()` to get it as a list

Comment: Hello Ben.T
Thanks for your help!
When i executing the below code: df['sentence'].loc[df['Column A'].str.contains("('<s>', '<s>')")] = 1
KeyError: '[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan] not in index'

Comment: @Balu not sure what it is without your exact input. try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before doing my answer, maybe there is a problem in index numbers

Comment: I tried with your code still i am facing the Same Problem  `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` 
Iam facing the below error
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))

KeyError: '[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan\n nan ] not in index'

Comment: @Balu what do you get if you do `type(df['Column A'].loc[0])`?

Comment: @Balu if it's `tuple`, try: `df['sentence'].loc[df['Column A'].str[0] == ('<s>', '<s>')] = 1` instead of the line where you got the error

Comment: @ Ben .T  Iam getting the output **str** for the below code `type(df['Column A'].loc[0])`

Comment: @ Ben T these are the datatypes of `DFdf.dtypes`

 **Column A       object**
 **Column B       float64**
 **dtype: object**

Comment: @ Ben T finally i got it 
Thanks for your support

Comment: @Balu good :) can you just tell me what the problem was in case it happens again?

Comment: @ Ben T i faced index Problem `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @ Ben .T  after create a column (sentence) with 0 then i ran the below command it was executed
 df['Column A'] = df['Column A'].astype(str)

Comment: @ BEn .T can you look the below post i was stickup here,can you have look the below link  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51036566/row-concatenation-logic)

Comment: @ Ben T. can you look the below post.albert gave the solution is working fine for me .but iam getting the data in *.txt format (multiple files) like (file.txt,file2.txt)I iam wondering so how can assign to it variable.   <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799185/how-to-read-multiple-files-in-a-loop-in-python-and-get-count-of-matching-words/51800458#51800458>