# How to Read Multiple Files in a Loop in Python and get count of matching words

Tags: python-3.x

I have two text files and 2 lists (FIRST_LIST,SCND_LIST),i want to find out count of each file matching words from FIRST_LIST,SCND_LIST individually.

FIRST_LIST =

```
"accessorizes","accessorizing","accessorized","accessorize"
```

SCND_LIST=

```
"accessorize","accessorized","accessorizes","accessorizing"
```

text File1 contains:

> This is a very good question, and you have received good answers which describe interesting topics accessorized accessorize.

text File2 contains:

> is more applied,using accessorize accessorized,accessorizes,accessorizing

output

```
File1 first list count=2
File1 second list count=0

File2 first list count=0
File2 second list count=4
```

This code i have tried to achive this functionality but not able to get the expected output.
if any help appreciated

```
import os 
import glob
files=[]

for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    files.append(filename)


# remove Punctuations
import re

def remove_punctuation(line):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)

two_files=[]
for filename in files:
    for line in open(filename):
        #two_files.append(remove_punctuation(line))
        print(remove_punctuation(line),end='')
        two_files.append(remove_punctuation(line))

FIRST_LIST = "accessorizes","accessorizing","accessorized","accessorize"

SCND_LIST="accessorize","accessorized","accessorizes","accessorizing"

c=[]
for match in FIRST_LIST:
    if any(match in value for value in two_files):
        #c=match+1
        print (match)
        c.append(match)
print(c)
len(c)
d=[]
for match in SCND_LIST:
    if any(match in value for value in two_files):
        #c=match+1
        print (match)
        d.append(match)
print(d)
len(d)
```

Comment: "but not able to get the expected output": what actually *is* your current result?

Comment: Your sample output is wrong since `accessorized` and `accessorizes` are part of both lists and will therefore be counted by consistent code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and some list comprehension is one of many different approaches to solve your problem.

I assume, your sample output being wrong since some words are part of both lists and both files but are not counted. In addition I added a second line to the sample strings in order to show how that is working with multi-line strings which might be the typical contents of a given file.

[`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) objects emulate your files, but working with real files from your file system works exactly the same since both provide a file-like object or file-like interface:

```
from collections import Counter

list_a = ["accessorizes", "accessorizing", "accessorized", "accessorize"]
list_b = ["accessorize", "accessorized", "accessorizes", "accessorizing"]

# added a second line to each string just for the sake
file_contents_a = 'This is a very good question, and you have received good answers which describe interesting topics accessorized accessorize.\nThis is the second line in file a'
file_contents_b = 'is more applied,using accessorize accessorized,accessorizes,accessorizing\nThis is the second line in file b'

# using io.StringIO to simulate a file input (--> file-like object)
# you should use `with open(filename) as ...` for real file input
file_like_a = io.StringIO(file_contents_a)
file_like_b = io.StringIO(file_contents_b)

# read file contents and split lines into a list of strings
lines_of_file_a = file_like_a.read().splitlines()
lines_of_file_b = file_like_b.read().splitlines()

# iterate through all lines of each file (for file a here)
for line_number, line in enumerate(lines_of_file_a):
    words = line.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split(' ')
    c = Counter(words)
    in_list_a = sum([v for k,v in c.items() if k in list_a])
    in_list_b = sum([v for k,v in c.items() if k in list_b])
    print("Line {}".format(line_number))
    print("- in list a {}".format(in_list_a))
    print("- in list b {}".format(in_list_b))


# iterate through all lines of each file (for file b here)
for line_number, line in enumerate(lines_of_file_b):
    words = line.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ').split(' ')
    c = Counter(words)
    in_list_a = sum([v for k,v in c.items() if k in list_a])
    in_list_b = sum([v for k,v in c.items() if k in list_b])
    print("Line {}".format(line_number))
    print("- in list a {}".format(in_list_a))
    print("- in list b {}".format(in_list_b))    


# actually, your two lists are the same
lists_are_equal = sorted(list_a) == sorted(list_b)
print(lists_are_equal)
```

Comment: Thanks albert appreciated for your help the solution is working for me because iam getting the data in *.txt format  (multiple files)
I am getting data in *.txt files iam wondering so how can assign to it variable.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted in order to close your question. What do you want to assign to a variable? If this is a more complex question, please file a new question.